# Initializing kernel module variables

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, wifi, linux-device-driver

I'm new to kernel and driver programming, so i hope my question is not too simple.

I'm working with a madwifi driver, in order to add some functionalities of my own. In my code i added some variables and structures that need to be initialized before the actual code starts.
While working i have encountered the following question:
where is the best place to put the functions that in charge of initializing this variables/structures? 
As far as i know, there is a special macro *module_init* which is being executed upon loading the module to the kernel, however, i could not find it in the madwifi driver code. What i have found instead is another famous macro, the *exit_module* though.
so my questions are:

1. Is it recommended to add an init_module and do all my initializations there?
2. Is it recommended to use the exit_module to free the allocated memory?

Thanks for the help!

Omer

Comment: By default, the `init_module` and `cleanup_module` functions are called on load/unload. The `module_init` can replace this by another function.

Comment: have you looked for __devinit...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every module (driver) defines two functions, one to be invoked when the module is loaded into the kernel and one for when the module is removed.
`module_init()` and `module_exit()` are the two special kernel **macros** to declare two functions for these roles.

I suppose your driver has init function. `init()` functions are generally used to initialize or register your driver.

Also check for the `probe()` function. If your driver can support multiple devices, once driver is registered, kernel calls `probe()` once for each device. This probe function starts the per-device initialization: initializing hardware, allocating resources, and registering the device with the kernel as a block or network device or whatever it is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as i mentioned, i couldn't find the init function in the code.. it seems it just doesn't exist.

Comment: A module will always have functions declared in the `module_init()` and `module_exit()` macros.  But the module may consist of more than one source file, so perhaps you are not looking in the file that has the init routine.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment, the initialization code can be in the `init_module` function.

Regarding your questions:

1. The module initialization function (`init_module`) is the right
   place for driver-level initialization. It's recommended to use it,
   unless your needs are trivial enough for C static variable
   initialization.
2. The cleanup function (`cleanup_module`) must make
   sure that the driver has released any resource it has allocated.
   It's the right place to free anything allocated during
   initialization.

Comment: I see...So if, for example, i wanted to create an array of buffers that i will be using throughout the whole module, you'd advise me to declare it and allocate memory for it in the init_module? (the same of all other vars\structures that are in use throughout the whole code)

Comment: Generally, you should allocate as little as possible, and avoid allocating lots of memory just in case - better wait for the need to arise. But if you do that - then yes, allocate in `init_module`, free in `cleanup_module`.

Comment: @omer, Thanks for saying "thanks", but the proper way to do it is to upvote or accept the answer.